# Problem with using expr

Tags: shell, quoting, string

I've got two strings

```
str1="( 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 ) / 3 + 5"
```

and

```
str2="( 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 ) / 3 + 5 * 2"
```

The command

```
result=` expr $str1`
```

returns a correct value, while

```
result=` expr $str2`
```

returns `expr: syntax error`

Comment: yes. quote it. `expr "$str2"`. Or use your shell: `str='(1+2+3+4+5)/3+5'; echo "$(($str))" "$(($str*2))"`

Comment: Do you have `5 * 2` or `5 \* 2` in `str2`? This isn't clear from what you posted. Please take a minute to go familiarize yourself with the formatting features on this site; you can see a guide by browsing through the buttons above the edit box and reading the help available by clicking on the `?` button.

Answer (score 2):

The following will produce wrong results:

```
str2="( 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 ) / 3 + 5 * 2"
expr $str2
```

The problem is that the shell considers `*` to be a wildcard file glob and will replace it with a list of files in the current directory.  This is not what you want.

`expr` is archaic.  A more modern solution would use the shell's `$((...))` form for arithmetic:

```
$ str2="( 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 ) / 3 + 5 * 2"
$ echo "$((str2))"
15
```

The shell only does integer arithmetic.  If you actually wanted floating-point accurate results (which happen to be the same here), use `bc`:

```
$ echo "$str2" | bc -l
15.00000000000000000000
```

Note that `$str2` is enclosed in double-quotes to prevent shell mischief.

Answer (score 1):

When you expand a variable outside of double quotes, as in `expr $str2`, the following things happen:

1. Take the value of the variable. The result is a string.
2. Split the value into whitespace-delimited chunks.¹ The result is a list of strings.
3. Interpret each element of the list as a wildcard pattern, i.e. [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)). If it matches files, replace the element by the list of matches. If it doesn't match any file, leave the element alone.

For example, the value of your variable contains the word `*`, which is replaced by the list of file names in the current directory.

Generally speaking, always put double quotes around variable substitutions and command substitutions: `"$stuff"`, `` "`stuff`" ``. See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) Only leave out the quotes if you know and understand why you need to leave out the quotes.

In this case, you need to have step 2 (splitting) happening, because `expr` needs the operators and operands in separate arguments. But step 3 (treating each word as a filename wildcard pattern) must not happen. You can do this by turning off globbing:

```
result=`set -f; expr $str2`
```

In ksh or bash, use an array instead of a string — but in these shells you wouldn't have any use for `expr`.

Unless you need your script to be portable to ancient Bourne shells, you don't need to use `expr`. Arithmetic expressions are a standard POSIX feature.

```
result=$(($str2))
```

¹  <sub>The separator characters can be configured via the `IFS` variable.</sub>